# Как получить фото в переменную, не скачивая на диск. Телеграмм бот (telebot)

Tags: vkontakte-api, telebot, selenium-webdriver

На данный момент, получение и отправка фото в вк, происходит таким образом. Хочется установить бота на бесплатный хостинг heroku, но там запись данных на сервер не предусматривается. Могу ли я как то без загрузки фото на диск получить тот же формат, что и при чтении из диска. Переменная downloaded_file передаёт байтовый объект. Ну и если кто знает, может предложите как можно реализовать телеграмм бота, на какой сервер(хостинг) его поставить, чтобы можно было работать и с selenium, которому нужен Chrome?

```
try:
        file_info = bot.get_file(message.photo[len(message.photo) - 1].file_id)
        downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)
        src = os.getcwd() + '\\' + message.photo[1].file_id + '.jpg'
        src_data.append(src)
        with open(src, 'wb') as new_file:
        new_file.write(downloaded_file)
except Exception as e:
        bot.reply_to(message,e )



 for src in src_data:
        files = {
            'file': (src, open(src, 'rb')),
        }
        response = requests.post(photo_url, files=files).json()
```

Answer (score 0):

Нет, вы не можете сделать такое. Проще выбрать другой бесплатный сервер (например pythonanywhere).